# Regex in which any one group must be compulsory

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Suppose I have a string as

```
Q2
```

There are many variations related to this string like

```
Q2
Quarter two
Quarter 2
2-Q
2.Q
Q.2
Q-2
Second Quarter
```

etc.

My regex is

```
((2)|(second))*\W*((q)|(quarter))\W*((2)|(second)|(two))*
```

If there is only "q" or "Quarter" regex will be match

I want any one group(1 or 7) to be compulsory

How can I do that?

Comment: You're already using *alternation* `|`. The pattern `a|b|c` means "match exactly one of `a`, `b` or `c`" (i.e., one of them is "compulsory"). Can you use this construct to get what you want?

Comment: ((2)|(second))* and  ((2)|(second)|(two))* is not compulsory bcoz I have kept *

Comment: So if there is only "Q" regex will be matched bcoz of this ((q)|(quarter))

Comment: `(2|second)*` would match `22222` or `second2second2`. Is that what you want? Do you know about `+`, which means "one or more" (like `*` means "zero or more")?

Comment: I mean to say Q and Quarter should be compulsory but 2 or two or second must be after or before "Q" | "Quarter"

Comment: I have given an example above

Comment: Why no to use regex like this ^(Q2|Quarter two|Quarter 2|2-Q|2.Q|Q.2|Q-2|Second Quarter)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try using a conditional group (and simplifying the regex a bit I think would make it more readable!):

```
(2|second)?[^\w\n]*(quarter|q)[^\w\n]*(?(1)|(2|second|two))
```

The conditional group means:

```
(?(1)          # If group 1 exists then:
               # Nothing
|              # Else
(2|second|two) # Get match this group
)
```

Also, it would be better using `?` (0 or 1 time) than `*` (0 or more times) which I already included in the above regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this regex. You can use `?:` inside the `(?:...)` if you do not want to capture the groups:

```
\b((Q[.-]?2)|(Quarter (two|2))|(2[-.]?Q)|(Second Quarter))\b
```

Basically it is using piped regex(total four) in it. You can get the explanation of the regex [from here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(((2|Second|two)(\s|-|\.)?(Quarter|Q))|(Quarter|Q)(\s|-|\.)?(2|Second|two))
```

The trick is moving `Quarter` to before `Q` so that `Quarter` will be checked first.

[DEMO](http://www.rexfiddle.net/P0G8hls)